# Is there a statistical test for sparsity?

Tags: statistical-significance, data-imputation, sparse

We are developing an algorithm that tries to reconstruct/impute missing data from sparse datasets. I would like to know how to asses or quantify the sparsity of a dataset? Is there an appropriate statistical significance test for it?

Comment: what do you mean by sparsity here? The number of missing values?

Comment: Not really. What do you mean by sparse? Sparsity has nothing to do with normality/not normality.

Comment: I have used entropy to present the sparsity of data. Thanks for all other answes.